# this.$el pointing to container element

Tags: backbone.js

I have two views, `ListView` and `ItemView`. `ItemView` is populated like this on `render` in `ListView`:

```
this.items.each(function(model, index) {
    new ItemView({
        item: model,
    });
});
```

All `ItemView` share the same container `el`; being a `<tbody>`, with its template being the `<tr>`.

When triggering events, they point to the containing element, causing e.g. `save` to trigger save on all `ItemView` rather than just the one that was clicked. Is there a way of circumventing this behavior, or is there a better practice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this one,

```
ListView = Backbone.View.extend({
        events : {
            'click tr' : function(e){
                       this.items.each(function(model){
                       model.trigger('save');
                  });
             }
        }
})
```

then bind save events in item view.

```
this.model.on('save', function(){
  //your code here
});
```